# Optimizar consulta COUNT en SQL

Tags: mysql, sql

Estoy creando una consulta en MySql (5.6.13) en la que necesito obtener la cuenta (`count`). He probado con el uso de `Case` de esta manera:

```
    Select case when t6.edad > 1 and t6.edad <=18 then COUNT(t6.edad) else 0 end as 'R1',
        case when t6.edad >= 19 and t6.edad <=40 then COUNT(t6.edad) else 0 end as 'R2',
        case when t6.edad >= 41 THEN COUNT(t6.edad) else 0 end as 'R3',
    from t1
INNER JOIN t2 on t1.id1 = t2.id1
INNER JOIN t3 on t2.id2 = t3.id2
INNER JOIN t4 on t1.id1 = t4.id1
INNER JOIN t5 on t1.id1 = t5.id3
INNER JOIN t6 on t5.id4 = t6.id4
where t1.activo = 1  and t1.fecha >='2020-07-01' and t1.fecha <='2020-07-01'
GROUP BY t6.edad;
```

Sin embargo el resultado me sale así:

```
r1  r2  r3
0   0   0
1   0   0
3   0   0
0   3   0
0   3   0
0   7   0
0   4   0
0   6   0
0   3   0
0   3   0
0   1   0
0   1   0
```

Posteriormente opté por crearlo de esta manera:

```
select total1.total as R1,
       total2.total as R2
    from 
    (
        Select COUNT(*) as total
            from t1
        INNER JOIN t2 on t1.id1 = t2.id1
        INNER JOIN t3 on t2.id2 = t3.id2
        INNER JOIN t4 on t1.id1 = t4.id1
        INNER JOIN t5 on t1.id1 = t5.id3
        INNER JOIN t6 on t5.id4 = t6.id4
        where t1.activo = 1  and t1.fecha >='2020-07-01' and t1.fecha <='2020-07-01' and t6.edad > 0 and t6.edad <=18
    ) as total1,
    (
        Select COUNT(*) as total
            from t1
        INNER JOIN t2 on t1.id1 = t2.id1
        INNER JOIN t3 on t2.id2 = t3.id2
        INNER JOIN t4 on t1.id1 = t4.id1
        INNER JOIN t5 on t1.id1 = t5.id3
        INNER JOIN t6 on t5.id4 = t6.id4
        where t1.activo = 1  and t1.fecha >='2020-07-01' and t1.fecha <='2020-07-01' and t6.edad >= 19 and t6.edad <=40
    ) as total2
```

Como se dan cuenta los `join` se repiten en cada consulta ¿hay una manera
de que solo se haga una vez los `join`?

**Observación: es necesario realizar sí o sí hacer todos los `join`.**

Comment: Hola, bienvenido a la comunidad. Te invito a hacer el [recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) y leer [¿cómo preguntar?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para que tu pregunta sea bien recibida por parte de la comunidad. Además, para poder reproducir tu problema y encontrar una solución fácilmente nos sería de gran ayuda un [ejemplo mínimo, completo y verificable](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Dicho esto, en este caso necesitamos que expliques con tus palabras qué quieres hacer con esa consulta SQL y, a ser posible, hacer algo para que podamos reproducir los datos.

Comment: Puedes agregar la base de datos que usas y la version por favor.

Comment: @DavElsanto, en parte es culpa mía porque cambié MySQL por SQL en el título por considerarlo una consulta SQL general y no especifica de un SGBD en particular. El OP ha agregado MySQL versión 5.6.13 en los datos de su pregunta. Por cierto Programador_J, ¿te sirvió mi respuesta?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Presupongo que lo que quieres obtener es la suma de los registros que están comprendidos entre rangos de edad. En ese caso estás haciendo mal la agrupación porque deberías obtener un único registro con los resultados, no un registro por cada valor agrupado de `t6.edad`, que es lo que estás obteniendo.

Para hacer el trabajo te propongo que hagas lo siguiente: cuando realizas una comparación el resultado es `1` si es cierto y `0` si es falso, por lo que puedes usar el operador `SUM()` para contar los registros cuya condición se cumpla:

```
SELECT
  SUM(edad BETWEEN 0 AND 18) entre_0_y_18,
  SUM(edad BETWEEN 19 AND 40) entre_19_y_40,
  SUM(edad >= 41) mas_de_41
FROM pruebas;
```

Para las edades comprendidas de 5 en 5 desde 5 hasta 75 (5, 10, 15, 20, 25, 30, 35, 40, 45, 50, 55, 60, 65, 70 y 75), el resultado sería:

```
entre_0_y_18 | entre_19_y_40 | mas_de_41
          3  |            5  |        7
```

Puedes ver el funcionamiento en línea en la siguiente URL:

- https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/jW7hocYtKRNSVVYYPANXww/0

---

Adaptado a tu consulta, quedaría algo así:

```
SELECT
  SUM(t6.edad BETWEEN 0 AND 18) R1,
  SUM(t6.edad BETWEEN 19 AND 40) R2,
  SUM(t6.edad >= 41) R3
FROM t1
INNER JOIN t2 ON t1.id1 = t2.id1
INNER JOIN t3 ON t2.id2 = t3.id2
INNER JOIN t4 ON t1.id1 = t4.id1
INNER JOIN t5 ON t1.id1 = t5.id3
INNER JOIN t6 ON t5.id4 = t6.id4
WHERE t1.activo = 1
  AND t1.fecha BETWEEN '2020-07-01' AND '2020-07-01'
```

---

Si vas a usar otro SGBD que no tenga esa conversión implícita entre tipos booleanos y enteros (postgres), puedes hacer uso de `CASE`:

```
SELECT
  SUM(CASE WHEN edad BETWEEN 0 AND 18 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) entre_0_y_18,
  SUM(CASE WHEN edad BETWEEN 19 AND 40 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) entre_19_y_40,
  SUM(CASE WHEN edad >= 41 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) mas_de_41
FROM pruebas;
```

Ver en línea en el siguiente enlace:

- https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/jW7hocYtKRNSVVYYPANXww/1

Comment: Agradecería que la persona que me dejó un -1 aclarase en un comentario el motivo por el que ha valorado negativamente la respuesta.

Comment: Gracias, realmente lo que necesito es obtener el número de personas que se encuentran en cada rango de edad, no la suma, la necesidad de crear todos los join es por que en la primer tabla obtengo la fecha y para llegar a la tabla donde esta la edad requiero hacer todos esos join. Ambas maneras que propuse me obtienes el resultado en la primera si hago la suma de cada columna me da el resultado esperado, pero lo ideal es que quede de está manera
`entre_0_y_18 | entre_19_y_40 | mas_de_41
          3  |            5  |        7`

Comment: ¿Podrías leer de nuevo mi respuesta? Es justo eso lo que hago, cuento las personas en cada rango de edad, pero lo hago usando `sum()` en vez de `count()` por los motivos que explico en la respuesta. También pongo una consulta adaptada a tus `join` como ejemplo de cómo hacer uso del método que te propongo.

Comment: Una Disculpa, ya analice tu respuesta y tienes razón no se me había ocurrido realizarlo de está manera, realmente tu respuesta me ayudo y soluciono el problema, gracias